# What are the benefits of ODBC versus a specific RDBMS API?

Tags: database, odbc

I believe ODBC has gotten to a point that it is more reliable and portable across both database engines and operating systems. There aren't too many opportunities for speed optimization if one should consider using a direct RDBMS API.

Also, ODBC abstraction, does make source code more portable so that migrating to a new RDBMS won't require complete code rewrite!

Nevertheless, using a direct API can out perform ODBC by removing layers of abstraction, and the specific RDBMS low level constraints can provide access to specific RDBMS full features.

What do you think of this ?

Comment: What's the question? This sounds like a statement.

Comment: I agree that is difficult to comment on the statement. Please reformulate the question as it appear to be too generic. What are you interested in? performaces, ease of programming, other?

Comment: Vote for closing, but still I think there's something good to learn from this question once it's actually a question.

Comment: Well that was a try to reformulate my ideas about the ODBC layer,
My real Question is: how much do you like the ODBC ? why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The queries sent through ODBC are not truly portable unless you use the dreaded [ODBC Escape Sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711838(VS.85).aspx). Even then, the 'portable' part is only a small subset of the SQL grammar (eg. no DDL).

Frankly, I never seen a project succeed at this. At best they support a set of tested drivers, like SQL/Oracle/DB2 and that's it. A much better approach is to abstract your application data access layer and provide a different implementation for each back-end you support.

Comment: Yes, tremendous work if have to do by yourself. Not tremendous (but costly), if someone has already done it and selling it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would get better overall flexibility in using ORM framework, like Hibernate or such (depending on the programming environment)...